# Connecting to sFTP from within an iOS App

Tags: ios, objective-c, networking, sftp

I'm new to Objective C and Xcode, but was wondering how to connect to a SFTP within my application. I've successfully connected to FTPs before, but was hoping to keep more secure in the future. When connecting with a regular computer you need a special SFTP client, so I wasn't sure what steps I'd have to take to connect within an iOS App.

Also, what are your opinions of SSH FTPs Vs. SFTPs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to download a library and put that into your app.  I would recommend Chilkat.  He has wrote a lot of stuff for sftp.

Good luck.

look at some of these (http://www.example-code.com/ios/sftp.asp)

Comment: Thanks, I'll have to look into that. Do you know if this replaces the need for a SFTP client, or rather functions as one?

Comment: I believe what your asking is if you need an additional program to run the functions of this package.  The answer is no.  With this code you can access your SFTP and do functions such as simple download and simple upload.

Answer (score 3):

There are plenty of open source libraries like [NMSSH](https://github.com/Lejdborg/NMSSH) or [DLSFTPClient](https://github.com/dleehr/DLSFTPClient). Please, don't use proprietary components, support open source.

Comment: I used [DLSFTPClient](https://github.com/dleehr/DLSFTPClient) for SFTP connection.So my question is what protocol its uses for connection with server.Basically my concern is the connection is secure or someone can track the user name and password.